# SQL multiple words search, ordered by number of matches

Tags: sql, search-multiple-words

I'm trying to compose an SQL SELECT query with multiple search words. But I want the result be ordered by number of words matches.

For example, let the search string is "red green blue". I want the results which contains all these three words on top, after that the results, which contains two of them, and at the end - only one word matches.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    (col LIKE '%red%') OR
    (col LIKE '%green%') OR
    (col LIKE '%blue%')
ORDER BY
    ?????
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
(
CASE 
WHEN  col LIKE '%red%' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END CASE
+     
CASE 
WHEN  col LIKE '%green%' THEN 1
ELSE 0 
END CASE
+    
CASE 
WHEN  col LIKE '%blue%' THEN 1
ELSE 0
END CASE
)  DESC
```

If your DB vendor has `IF`, you can use it instead of `CASE` (e.g., for Mysql  you can write
    `IF (col LIKE '%red% , 1,0) + IF(....'`

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you using?  if SQL Server, then it sounds like a Full Text Search archtecture would be your best fit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx